# Accessing objects by name from dict

Tags: django, django-templates

Users can have multiple lists and I have DataItem objects attached to lists, these DataItem objects have number values and now I would need to retrieve all values by list name and insert them to chart.js My **view** looks like this:

```
@login_required
def app(request):
    form = list_form
    form2 = data_form(user=request.user)
    user = request.user.pk
    user_lists = List.objects.filter(user=user)
    #Here I have lists in dict but I have no idea how to call them in template.
    list_data = {}
    for list in user_lists:
        list_data[list.name] = DataItem.objects.filter(list=list)

    context = {'user_lists': user_lists, 'form': form, 'form2': form2,
    'list_data': list_data}

    return render(request, 'app/app.html', context)
```

**Template:** this is the chart.js datasets part in html page and it displays the list names properly how do I call the values that are connected to those names?

```
{% for list in user_lists %}
 {
     label: '{{ list.name }}',
     data: [?????????],
 },
{% endfor %}
```

**Models** if needed

```
class List(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['name', 'user']

    @property
    def chart_data(self):
        return ', '.join([str(x.data) for x in self.data_items])



class DataItem(models.Model):
    data = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='data_items')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you need integer data for your charts, the simple solution is add property to your `List` model:

```
class List(models.Model):
            name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
            user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')

    @property
    def chart_data(self):
        return ', '.join([str(x.data) for x in self.data_items.all()])
```

and in the template:

```
{% for list in user_lists %}
 {
     label: '{{ list.name }}',
     data: [{{ list.chart_data }}],
 },
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: using that my chart dissappears so something wrong, if I add [] to "list.data_items" then the chart does not dissappear but I do not see my values.. I have no glue where to start digging for solutions..

Comment: I see the chart but there is no labels or data in it

Comment: it gives error "'RelatedManager' object is not iterable" I edit the post and see if I used property correctly

Comment: Also gives this to the shell "ImportError: cannot import name 'List' from 'app.models'"

Comment: Got it working, thanks for help! It is appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop list_data a dictionary object.

`DataItem.objects.filter(list=list)` must return list item not query item.
So Try to get List of values you need. eg

```
DataItem.objects.filter(list=list).values_list('data',flat=True)
```

**list_data contain both label name and data**. 
`key` as `label` and `value` as `data`

Since you have key and value. You do not need to loop user_lists

```
{% for key, value in list_data.items %}
{
   label: '{{key}}',
     data: '{{value}}',
}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: something making the chart not work in this, chart dissappears whit that.. anyideas?

Comment: @JoonasMykkänen, Please submit the error. Are you expecting data from DataItem ? then try this. DataItem.objects.filter(list=list).values_list('data',flat=True)

Comment: It does not give error, the data just doesnt show up, chart appears to be empty! And im expecting list of DataItems related to object List, users can have multiple lists!

Comment: I am not getting what exact format data is needed for your chart.

Comment: DataItems are just numbers. then it shows line chart from those numbers. Sounded simple in my head first but nah